# How to copy or move files without being asked to overwrite?

Tags: shell, alias, cp

What I've tried:

```
root@host [/home1]# cp -f hello /home3
cp: omitting directory `hello'
root@host [/home1]# cp -rf hello /home3
cp: overwrite `/home3/hello/.buildpath'? y
cp: overwrite `/home3/hello/.bash_logout'? y
cp: overwrite `/home3/hello/.project'? ^C
```

They always ask me whether I want to overwrite. Using mv doesn't work either. So what should I do?

Other things I tried:

```
root@host [/home1]# cp -rf hello /home3
cp: overwrite `/home3/hello/.buildpath'? y
cp: overwrite `/home3/hello/.bash_logout'? y
cp: overwrite `/home3/hello/.project'? ^C
root@host [/home1]# cp -force hello /home3
cp: invalid option -- 'o'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
root@host [/home1]# cp --remove-destination hello /home4
cp: omitting directory `hello'
root@host [/home1]# cp --remove-destination hello /home3
cp: omitting directory `hello'
root@host [/home1]# cp --remove-destination -r hello /home3
cp: overwrite `/home3/hello/.buildpath'? ^C
root@host [/home1]#
```

Comment: Could you give the output of `alias cp`?

Comment: Also, `type cp` as well as `ls -l` on one of the target files may provide useful information.

Comment: cp is copy. Okay it may be an alias. So what's the command?

Answer (score 19):

For force overwrite without asking you should use the command **mv** and the option "-f", use man to see the options.

man mv:

```
   -f, --force
          do not prompt before overwriting
```

Example:

```
mv -f test.tmp test.txt
```

Comment: FYI, on macOS `--force` can't be used. Just `-f`. I know, I was surprised as well. I usually like to use the more explicit options when they are available, but in this case it's not - on macOS anyway.

Answer (score 15):

`cp` appears to be either aliased to something which is causing problems, or it is a function. You can remove the alias/function:

```
unalias cp
unset -f cp
```

If you'd rather just override it right now, you can use the `command` command to override any alias/function definitions:

```
command cp [...]
```

If you'd rather totally remove this, you probably have to look in your bash startup files.

Comment: `\cp` will also avoid the alias.

Comment: Yup, you are correct `which cp => alias cp='cp -i; /bin/cp`. Thanks Amazon!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an alias for cp. You can override this alias by doing:

```
\cp -f hello /home3
```

This has the adventage of not modifying your aliases setup, as it is overriding it just for this call.

Answer (score 1):

Try cp -rv /sourcefileordirectory /Destinationfolder

Comment: will t his work? What does -rv mean?

Comment: `-rv` means recursive and verbose. So this should copy the files and subfolders, and output the progress to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

just execute `alias cp=cp` and it will overwrite the target without asking in this session. If you want to have it stored as standard behavior, store it in your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yes`, which is designed for this sort of thing. It will automatically print `y` and answer these prompts for you:

```
yes | cp -f hello /home3
```